# User a conditional foreign key, one or the other

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, Employees, and Customers.  Employees and Customer data is coming from a web service call that I have no control over.  In the web service calls both an Employee and a Customer are represented with a Guid for their ID.

I need to keep track of some setting data for Employees and Customers, Last Logon time, etc so I have created a Table in Sql Server called AuthenticatedUsers.

On the AuthenticatedUsers table I have the following Columns
 -Id (Guid)
 -Email (nchar(250))
 -NameIdentifier (nchar(250))
 -LastLoggedOn (DateTime)
 -IsLockedOut (bit)

Employees are migrated to a new employee table from the web service call, as are custmers (the web service is really just for shared data and validating credentials).

As such in order for a customer or employee to log in, they will exist in the customer or employee table.

So my delimma is, How do I put a contraint on the authenticated users Id column so that either A: A customer with that ID must already exist in the Cusutomer Table or B: An employee with that Id must exist in the Employee table.

I would just use a Check Constraint but you can't use sub queries in check constraints.  And I'm not sure it's possible to create a foreign key from Id -> CustomerId and Id -> Employee.Id.

The only thing I can think of is to change the Primary key on AuthenticatedUsers to an Auto ID, and then adding a Column for CustomerID and EmployeeID, but I would ideally like to avoid doing that.

Comment: I realize you say you have no control over this, but for futre readers, the real solutuion is that the database struture is incorrect and needs to be changed. What you need is a people table that the employee and customers are chilrden of. Then the Fks can be against that table.

Comment: I'm refactoring the database to do that now.  AuthenticatedUsers became User, and AuthenticatedUserType became UserType.  A Customer cannot exist with a user record, and an Employee Cannot Exist without a User record.  I have control over that, I just don't have control over the Guid being the ID and the data coming back from the service.  And now I have the added bonus of being able to create an Insert/Update trigger on the user table to automatically create the customer or employe record, or update them.

Answer (score 0):

one approach is

you can have two columns .   `EmployeeId`, `CustomerId` in the AuthenticatedUsers table 
with `foreign key` constraint to `Employers` and `Customers` respectively

one of these column values will be NULL , which would be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm attempting to do it with a trigger before I cave into that using an instead of insert trigger.  I could also do a UDF, but was hoping there was a better way than both.